# Android ant debug fails with android library (Absolut path)

Tags: android, ant, build-process, android-library

I have a fresh android project (APP) and a fresh android lib project (LIB) under MacOS or Linux, created by command line as explained in http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html.

APP builds with ant debug successfully (no LIB connected). When I link the library from the APP's folder with a relative path as in:

```
android update project --library ../TestLib --target android-9 --name TestApp --path .
```

Everything is fine, ant debug builds the APP. But when I link it with an absolute path as in

```
android update project --library /Users/<path-to-lib-folder>/TestLib --target android-9 --name TestApp --path .
```

the ant debug build fails.

Why is there a difference between absolute and relative paths? In our automated ant build process we need to employ absolute paths.. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

the `--library` is the library project **relative** to your project directory. In my case (I'm using Linux):

```
libproject$ pwd
/home/me/workspace/libproject
myapp$ pwd
/home/me/workspace/myapp
myapp$ android update project --library ../libproject --target android-15 --name MyApp --path .
```

It should give this result.

```
Resolved location of library project to: /home/me/workspace/libproject
Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
Updated file ./build.xml
Updated file ./proguard-project.txt
```